# How to group selection by a specific parent -> child combination?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have an XML that consists of a `<div>` in which `<div><head>` occur. These `<div><head>` might or might not be followed by a `<lb>`.
Ideally, I'd like a list of all `<div><head/> ... </div>`

```
<div><div><head facs="#facs_21_TextRegion_1624455438571_399">
            <lb facs="#facs_21_line_1624455438683_402" n="N001"/><supplied reason="article_added">7</supplied> Von der Liebe und guten wercken.</head>
            <p facs="#facs_21_TextRegion_1624455467191_408">
               <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l25" n="N001"/>Die Liebe, die da ist das ende des Gebots und die
               <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l26" n="N002"/>volkommenheyt des Gesetzs,<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref type="biblical" cRef="Rm_13,8-10">Röm 13,8-10</ref>; <ref type="biblical" cRef="Gal_5,14">Gal 5,14</ref>.</note> so bald sie inn der
               <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l28" n="N003"/>rechtfertigung eintritt, so ist sie fruchtbar und
               <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l29" n="N004"/>beschleüsset inn sich selbs die samen aller guten werck,<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref type="biblical" cRef="Ps_1,3">Ps 1,3</ref>.</note> <w>wel<pc>-</pc>
               <lb/><note place="margin-left" facs="#facs_21_r1">
               <lb/>Psalm. 1.</div> <div><head facs="#facs_21_TextRegion_1624455438571_399">
            <lb facs="#facs_21_line_1624455438683_402" n="N001"/><supplied reason="article_added">7</supplied> Von der Liebe und guten wercken.</head>
            <p facs="#facs_21_TextRegion_1624455467191_408">
               <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l25" n="N001"/>Die Liebe, die da ist das ende des Gebots und die
               <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l26" n="N002"/>volkommenheyt des Gesetzs,<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref type="biblical" cRef="Rm_13,8-10">Röm 13,8-10</ref>; <ref type="biblical" cRef="Gal_5,14">Gal 5,14</ref>.</note> so bald sie inn der
               <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l28" n="N003"/>rechtfertigung eintritt, so ist sie fruchtbar und
               <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l29" n="N004"/>beschleüsset inn sich selbs die samen aller guten werck,<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref type="biblical" cRef="Ps_1,3">Ps 1,3</ref>.</note> <w>wel<pc>-</pc>
               <lb/><note place="margin-left" facs="#facs_21_r1">
               <lb/>Psalm. 1.</div></div>
```

so I did `print(soup.find_all('div'))` which returns the list of all divs but removes the `<head>`:

```
<div>
<lb facs="#facs_21_line_1624455438683_402" n="N001"></lb><supplied reason="article_added">7</supplied> Von der Liebe und guten wercken.
            <p facs="#facs_21_TextRegion_1624455467191_408">
<lb facs="#facs_21_r3l25" n="N001"></lb>Die Liebe, die da ist das ende des Gebots und die
               <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l26" n="N002"></lb>volkommenheyt des Gesetzs,<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref cref="Rm_13,8-10" type="biblical">Röm 13,8-10</ref>; <ref cref="Gal_5,14" type="biblical">Gal 5,14</ref>.</note> so bald sie inn der
               <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l28" n="N003"></lb>rechtfertigung eintritt, so ist sie fruchtbar und
               <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l29" n="N004"></lb>beschleüsset inn sich selbs die samen aller guten werck,<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref cref="Ps_1,3" type="biblical">Ps 1,3</ref>.</note> <w>wel<pc>-</pc>
<lb></lb><note facs="#facs_21_r1" place="margin-left">
<lb></lb>Psalm. 1.</div>
```

I think some questions come up:

1. How can I group my soup by

   ```
   <div><head>some tags and text ...</head>some more text</div>
   ```
2. Why is the `<head>` vanishing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behavior comes from the `bs4` [standard parser `lxml`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) in my opinion, so if you switch to `html.parser` you should see the `<head>`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
```

You could use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to chain your condition:

```
soup.select('div:has(>head)')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div><div><head facs="#facs_21_TextRegion_1624455438571_399">
<lb facs="#facs_21_line_1624455438683_402" n="N001"/><supplied reason="article_added">7</supplied> Von der Liebe und guten wercken.</head>
<p facs="#facs_21_TextRegion_1624455467191_408">
<lb facs="#facs_21_r3l25" n="N001"/>Die Liebe, die da ist das ende des Gebots und die
<lb facs="#facs_21_r3l26" n="N002"/>volkommenheyt des Gesetzs,<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref type="biblical" cRef="Rm_13,8-10">Röm 13,8-10</ref>; <ref type="biblical" cRef="Gal_5,14">Gal 5,14</ref>.</note> so bald sie inn der
<lb facs="#facs_21_r3l28" n="N003"/>rechtfertigung eintritt, so ist sie fruchtbar und
<lb facs="#facs_21_r3l29" n="N004"/>beschleüsset inn sich selbs die samen aller guten werck,<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref type="biblical" cRef="Ps_1,3">Ps 1,3</ref>.</note> <w>wel<pc>-</pc>
<lb/><note place="margin-left" facs="#facs_21_r1">
<lb/>Psalm. 1.</div> <div><head facs="#facs_21_TextRegion_1624455438571_399">
<lb facs="#facs_21_line_1624455438683_402" n="N001"/><supplied reason="article_added">7</supplied> Von der Liebe und guten wercken.</head>
<p facs="#facs_21_TextRegion_1624455467191_408">
<lb facs="#facs_21_r3l25" n="N001"/>Die Liebe, die da ist das ende des Gebots und die
<lb facs="#facs_21_r3l26" n="N002"/>volkommenheyt des Gesetzs,<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref type="biblical" cRef="Rm_13,8-10">Röm 13,8-10</ref>; <ref type="biblical" cRef="Gal_5,14">Gal 5,14</ref>.</note> so bald sie inn der
<lb facs="#facs_21_r3l28" n="N003"/>rechtfertigung eintritt, so ist sie fruchtbar und
<lb facs="#facs_21_r3l29" n="N004"/>beschleüsset inn sich selbs die samen aller guten werck,<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref type="biblical" cRef="Ps_1,3">Ps 1,3</ref>.</note> <w>wel<pc>-</pc>
<lb/><note place="margin-left" facs="#facs_21_r1">
<lb/>Psalm. 1.</div></div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

soup.select('div:has(>head)')
```

##### Output

```
[<div><head facs="#facs_21_TextRegion_1624455438571_399">
 <lb facs="#facs_21_line_1624455438683_402" n="N001"></lb><supplied reason="article_added">7</supplied> Von der Liebe und guten wercken.</head>
 <p facs="#facs_21_TextRegion_1624455467191_408">
 <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l25" n="N001"></lb>Die Liebe, die da ist das ende des Gebots und die
 <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l26" n="N002"></lb>volkommenheyt des Gesetzs,<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref cref="Rm_13,8-10" type="biblical">Röm 13,8-10</ref>; <ref cref="Gal_5,14" type="biblical">Gal 5,14</ref>.</note> so bald sie inn der
 <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l28" n="N003"></lb>rechtfertigung eintritt, so ist sie fruchtbar und
 <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l29" n="N004"></lb>beschleüsset inn sich selbs die samen aller guten werck,<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref cref="Ps_1,3" type="biblical">Ps 1,3</ref>.</note> <w>wel<pc>-</pc>
 <lb></lb><note facs="#facs_21_r1" place="margin-left">
 <lb></lb>Psalm. 1.</note></w></p></div>,
 <div><head facs="#facs_21_TextRegion_1624455438571_399">
 <lb facs="#facs_21_line_1624455438683_402" n="N001"></lb><supplied reason="article_added">7</supplied> Von der Liebe und guten wercken.</head>
 <p facs="#facs_21_TextRegion_1624455467191_408">
 <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l25" n="N001"></lb>Die Liebe, die da ist das ende des Gebots und die
 <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l26" n="N002"></lb>volkommenheyt des Gesetzs,<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref cref="Rm_13,8-10" type="biblical">Röm 13,8-10</ref>; <ref cref="Gal_5,14" type="biblical">Gal 5,14</ref>.</note> so bald sie inn der
 <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l28" n="N003"></lb>rechtfertigung eintritt, so ist sie fruchtbar und
 <lb facs="#facs_21_r3l29" n="N004"></lb>beschleüsset inn sich selbs die samen aller guten werck,<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref cref="Ps_1,3" type="biblical">Ps 1,3</ref>.</note> <w>wel<pc>-</pc>
 <lb></lb><note facs="#facs_21_r1" place="margin-left">
 <lb></lb>Psalm. 1.</note></w></p></div>]
```